# Static files not showing on express server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, server

**I am currently trying to get my JS express server to display my static HTML files using this code.**

[My JS Express code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3zHX.png)

**When I run my server I get this error message Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat: and the directory path to the file.  the directory path exists so I don't understand why it wont show the file and its contents. could someone explain this to me please. **

*What I have tried in addition to my written code.*

**I have tried changing the location of my project entirely and that didn't work.
I have tried using app.use, __Fileneme instead of __dirname, rewriting the code nothing works.

Im using Node. js I have express installed and required I have rewritten the code several times to be sure the error was not syntax error "although VS code would have made me aware of any syntax errors" I just at a loss now. this is a simple server that should display my html files just fine yet nothing I do works.**

Answer (score 0):

try adding this line at the top:
// where /public is the folder where 'welcome.html' is

```
 app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname+'/../public'));
```

the npm **path** package may be helpful as well

```
app.get('/Home', (req, res) => {
  console.log(path.join(__dirname ,'/public/welcome.html'));
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname ,'/public/welcome.html'));
})
```

Comment: Thank you but this did not work

Comment: I updated my answer above, try again and check the path in console

Comment: ok will do I will update you on the progress Thank you. I have seen others use the public path is it just a folder in the path?

Comment: the 'public' it's just a folder and it's a convention to call it that way. You can put the name you want but you must add it to express: 
app.use('/some-name', express.static(__dirname+'/some-name'));

Comment: So i gave it a try and it didn't work its states that the path is undefined. it dose log the pathway but it doesn't show the file content.

Comment: Thank you for the assist figured things out.

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();



app.use(express.static('public',{
  extensions: ['html', 'htm']
}));

// Listen to the App Engine-specified port, or 8080 otherwise
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

Comment: This solution did not work either thank you Ronnie.

Comment: I just tried again. at this point I have been able at least show that the pathway is in fact not missing. When the server runs it logs my pathway without the error. However, I am still short of the desired outcome.

Comment: When I use the sendFile key phrase it will show the error ENOENT no such file or directory. the send key phrase displays the pathway.

Comment: Figured things out. Thank you for the assist guys.